# PDO.How i can use this function?

Tags: php, security, pdo, implode

I'm very new at PDO and i write this code.But this code is unsecure.

```
function update_user($update_data) {
global $pdo;

$update = array();

foreach($update_data as $field=>$data){
$update[] = '`'. $field.'` = \''. $data.'\''; 
}
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . implode(', ', $update) ."WHERE user_id = " .$_SESSION['user_id']);
$query->execute();
```

}

I ask the internet about this code and become this:

```
function update_user($update_data) {
global $pdo;
$sql = "UPDATE users SET ".pdoSet($update_data,$values)." WHERE id = :id";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$values["id"] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$stm->execute($values);
```

}

But ,i do not know what i must write in the function pdoSet.Sorry when my english is not so good.

Comment: I found this post which might assist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684191/pdo-bindparam-into-one-statement

Comment: It should be `$values[":id"]`

Comment: @DreamEater no it doesn't matter

Comment: @PeeHaa Is that so? AFAIK, using `:id` in sql statement, needs the passed array to have `:id` as an index.

Comment: @PeeHaa you're in right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function in my other answer because it is present in the PDO tag wiki which I linked.
But okay, I can paste it here for you.

```
function pdoSet($fields, &$values, $source = array()) {
  $set = '';
  $values = array();
  if (!$source) $source = &$_POST;
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($source[$field])) {
      $set.="`".str_replace("`","``",$field)."`". "=:$field, ";
      $values[$field] = $source[$field];
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

This function intended to make inserts easier and safer.
However, if using functions is not familiar to you, better go for the other solution from the previous answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry i don't saw the link :) It's work now.Thank you for the posting.