# PDO update prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[pdo-bindparam-into-one-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684191/pdo-bindparam-into-one-statement)

I'm very new to PDO and I think I'm lost..
What I wanted to was using same variables for insert and update both..

```
 function pdoSet($fields, &$values, $source = array()){
    $set = '';
    $values = array();
    if(!$source) $source = &$_POST;
    foreach($fields as $field){
        if(isset($source[$field])){
            $set .= " $field =:$field, ";
            $values[$field] = $source[$field];
        }
    }
    return substr($set, 0, -2);
}

$fields = array(
    'name'
    , 'part'
    , 'tel'
    , 'email'
    , 'title'
    , 'contents'
);

if(!$idx){
    $fields[] = 'reg_date';
    $values[] = 'now()';
    $st = $pdo -> prepare("insert into qna_board set ".pdoSet($fields, $values));
}else{
    $st = $pdo -> prepare("update qna_board set ".pdoSet($fields, $values)." where idx = :idx");
    $st ->bindParam(':idx', $idx);
}

$st->execute($values);
```

It was successful for insert, but not for update.
When I used $idx instead of :idx it worked..
Could you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either `bind` parameters *or* pass them to `execute`. You cannot do both at once, PDO will discard any bound parameters when you pass any to `execute`. So your `idx` isn't bound when executing the query. Easiest fix:

```
$st->execute($values + compact('idx'));
```

You're opening yourself up to good old SQL injection by accepting raw field names from `$_POST` BTW.

Also, BTW:

```
join(', ', array_map(
    function ($field) { return "`$field` = :$field"; },
    $fields
))
```

A little saner than `.= '.., '` and `substr`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!!! I should think about accepting raw field names part more

Answer (score 0):

What are the current queries you are getting now? Then we can better see what is going wrong.

You should be careful by just using $_POST as $source in the prepared statement. Someone can inject SQL into your query. Always sanitize the input for a query.

In the pdoSet you are clearing the function argument $values and because this is given by reference (&$values) you are introducing side-effects in the rest of the code.